# Download the content of a page with load more on scroll down

Tags: android, okhttp

Is there any way to use `okhttp` to download a page's content with a load more on scrolled down feature?

My current solution is using a `WebView` and programmatically scroll down, check the content for the load more view, scroll down again and so on until no more content is loaded. Then I process the content of the `WebView`.

I want to switch over with this process to using `okhttp`. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link if that can help [OkHttp, Android - download a html page and display this content in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541733/okhttp-android-download-a-html-page-and-display-this-content-in-a-view) , by this you'll download the complete page, but for partial loading there might some working required at server end or in request call.

Comment: the load more content java script call (that is executed if the user scrolls down to the end of the page) won't be executed if  I just load the url with `okhttp`. So this is just the simple default method to load content, which of course works, but I need the whole page's content (after the user scrolled down, waited for the next content, scrolled down again, waited again, and so on). I don't know if this is possible with `okhttp`... And I'm not under control of the page, so all I can do is adjust my request or request techique..

Comment: i doubt for doing this with okhttp as its just simply define your request and get the reference response, can you call that script from a page url or api that in response provide remaining page content.

Comment: I doubt it as well, but technically it may work by enabling javascript and sending some scroll events and evalute in a callback how often this should be done or similar... I do it like that with the `WebView` already...